# Display Months in dropdown for filtering

Tags: views

I want to create a view over a content type. Over this page I want a select list of Months to filter the content by month.

Is there any module or how can I achieve this by view?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) project, you can add a "Date: Date (node)" (D7, not sure how it is called in D6) filter, where you can choose the granularity. By setting it to month, it will display a list of months in the filter.

I looks like a "All month" option is however currently missing, so you can't display all months by default, it seems. See http://drupal.org/node/574820.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Archive module](http://drupal.org/project/archive), although it isn't a view.  Alternatively, you don't need a module.  You could try a [View using arguments](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-create-monthly-archive-block-drupal-blog-views) or even just use the default archive that's built into views.  Following the example I linked to will be close to what you need.  For more information, [see here](http://drupalsn.com/learn-drupal/drupal-tutorials/how-create-simple-news-archive-drupal).